# Cant get a basic ASP.Net 5 website working on Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core

I have a very basic ASP.Net 5 application that I created following this guide https://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6, and it works grate from VS.

However I cant get that to work on azurewebsites. I keep getting the yellow runtime error page on the browser and this exception on the log file:

```
<EventData>
  <Data>3005</Data>
  <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
  <Data>11/22/2014 9:39:33 PM</Data>
  <Data>11/22/2014 9:39:33 PM</Data>
  <Data>9e1c1ecb36f647ddb1f4b1856b2a105c</Data>
  <Data>1</Data>
  <Data>1</Data>
  <Data>0</Data>
  <Data>/LM/W3SVC/46675609/ROOT-1-130611659736590153</Data>
  <Data></Data>
  <Data>/</Data>
  <Data>D:\home\site\wwwroot\</Data>
  <Data>RD00155D431959</Data>
  <Data></Data>
  <Data>21084</Data>
  <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
  <Data>IIS APPPOOL\glMigrations</Data>
  <Data>DirectoryNotFoundException</Data>
  <Data>
    Couldn't find package 'KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1'. Locations probed:

    D:\home\site\approot\packages\Migrations\1.0.0\packages\KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1
    D:\home\site\approot\packages\Migrations\packages\KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1
    D:\home\site\approot\packages\packages\KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1
    D:\home\site\approot\packages\KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1
    D:\home\site\packages\KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1
    D:\home\packages\KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1
    D:\packages\KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1
    at AspNet.Loader.KRuntimeLocator.GetPathToSpecificKrePackage(DirectoryInfo appPhysicalPath, String krePackage)
    at AspNet.Loader.KRuntimeLocator.LocateKRuntime(MapPathHelper mapPathHelper, Boolean&amp; isCoreClr, String relativeAppBasePath)
</Data>
```

I tried with the core and the full version and got the same results.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: How and what do you deploy?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same error when deploying to a local IIS server. The issue turned out to be caused by the project build settings not having "Produce outputs on build" ticked. I've just tried running my test project on Azure Website and managed to get it working.

I also had another issue deploying to the default "Free" plan website, as I was using the X64 KRE and only the "Basic" and "Standard" plans support X64.

I wrote a [Blog Post](http://codedbeard.com/asp-net-5-0-deploy-to-local-iis/) on how I got ASP.NET 5.0 working on local IIS, which I've updated with the Azure website findings, as my rep here is not high enough to post pictures.

Edit:
In case the link to my blog post breaks the following is a basic description of the steps I took to get ASP.Net 5.0 running on IIS and then Azure Websites

- Created an ASP.NET 5.0 Site using the Visual Studio 2015 Preview template running on Windows 10 Technical preview
- For the local IIS I then ensured that IIS had all the required features, which you can obviously skip for azure
- I then changed the "Build Settings" of the project to enable "Produce Outputs on Build" for both "Debug" and "Release" configurations
- Next I updated the project.json file to use the url I had configured in IIS, again this may not be necessary for azure
- I then created a Publishing profile to the local IIS server, which worked nicely.
- Having seen this post, I then attempted to deploy to Azure by simply creating a new publishing profile targeting Azure Websites
- I came across a similar error at this point, as I was targeting the X64 KRE, and the default Azure Website had been created as a "Free" site which does not support X64.
- I then changed the Azure Website to the "Basic" plan, and enable X64 cpu.
- Finally I redeployed using the earlier created Azure Publishing profile, Which this time resulted in a working site